# EXCEL Track two cell values(date) in which values between two need to sum to reach a certain amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns of data: DATE, KIND, NUMBER (ordered in date).

The data show how many fruits of each kind (possibly more than 2 kinds) are bought(+) and used(-) for cooking.

Excel data look like

[image]

Assuming that I always use the earliest bought fruit first, I would like to keep the track of when the fruits, which I used for cooking, are bought.

For example,

on 7/20, I use 2 of 5 apples bought on (7/5)
and have 3 leftovers bought on (7/5)

on 07-21 I use 11 apples bought between 7/5 and 7/15
and have 2 leftovers bought on (7/15)

11 = 3(7/5) + 5(7/10) + 3(7/15)

I would like to use formulas to automatically reflect

1. When the fruits, which are used for cooking, are bought (from when to when)?
2. How many fruits become leftovers after cooking?

Excel data with formula would show (D1-F1)

[image]

[EXCEL DATA ON GOOGLE SPREAD](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DyexbFpff0I7WVHZ9M3r9z5eaWC2YHuNDE7QhzmEC38/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is my first time posting, so if there is any mistake or rule I did not follow, please inform me and I will fix as soon as possible. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Check your Google Sheet I've solved the issue there. Check & comment here whether is working or not then I'll post my answer here also.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I think I did not explain the issue correctly... What I would like to do is to keep the record of fruits' "purchase date" used for cooking so that I can track back how old the fruits were when used for cooking. I succeeded in solving the issue with one kind of fruit but have trouble with  multiple kinds on same sheet. I will set up what I did on Sheet 2 with one kind first for better explanation

Comment: your current screen shot has day to day (Date wise) purchase records, if you want to check that how may Apples brought between Dates in that case also the formula I've shown will work with little modification !

Comment: Check your sheet I've modified it For other fruits.

Comment: Confirm edited Google sheet has worked for you or not,, I'm sure it's working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To keep the record of fruits' "purchase date" used for cooking, do the following:*

[image]

Write this formula in cell **B10** & fill down.

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C8, B2:B8, "="&A10, A2:A8, ">="&$C$10, A2:A8, "<="&$D$10)
```

**Note,**

- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.
- `C10` is Start Date & `D10` is End Date, you can change them as you need,
  formula  will calculate accordingly.
- This formula also can be used to "Count Fruits Used" for this, use Range
  `D2:D8` instead of `C2:C8`.